# Identity column and using order by in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and have a table with an `id` column as `identity(1,1)`. If I want to get query ordered by id column, do must use `Order By ID` or not necessary.

**EDIT :**
I have a unique clustered index on ID column. do this index guaranteed that my query sorted by id by default.

Comment: Do you mean is the table ordered by ID by default?

Comment: If you want it ordered by ID then specify it.

Comment: @codingbiz: yes do my query ordered by id by default?

Comment: I just updated my answer to follow your EDIT. Clustered index could not be used in some scenarios. That means, that its order was not evaluated at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases when ORDER BY is omitted - the order is unpredictable. Because such a SQL Statement does not ask for explicit order, SQL Server can return results when they are ready.

And that means:

- that the order is absolutely dependent on the execution plan.
- the order returned for some filter criteria, could differ in other
  case
- clustered index could be in some scenarios even **NOT** used for some execution plans. And in those cases (when not used) - its order is not taken into account.

For some select could be used other covering index, (which is not order by ID). And that will result in the "unexpected" order.

If we need to get **Ordered list**, we have to use explicit ORDER BY clause. Then we can be sure about the order. Only then.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default sort order. Even if the table has a *clustered index*, you are not guaranteed to get the results in that order.

You **MUST** specify the `ORDER BY` clause to your desired sort order.

Answer (score 1):

When “ORDER BY” is not used order of the table is not guaranteed.